# Force async Task to run sync

Tags: c#, task, sensenet

I have a method that uses an client SDK (sensenet) to make requests Sensenet.

```
private static async Task CreateFolder(String parentPath, String folderName)
    {

        SensenetRepository.WriteLog(typeof(SensenetRepository).Name, "Init CreateFolder: " + parentPath + "/" + folderName);

        var folder = Content.CreateNew(parentPath, "Folder", folderName);
        await folder.SaveAsync();

    }
```

I have to integrate this on my current api that is fully synchronous. (Do it all asynchronous will require a big changes on the clients and on the structure of the project)

To run "CreateFolder" synchronous, I'm calling like this:

```
CreateFolder(pathEntity, fileDate).Wait(); //seems to not stop here
//more code to execute after createFolder...
```

On CreateFolder execution it seems that is running asynchronous despite having Wait() calling.

I'm having difficult to call CreateNew method from Sensenet Client, since the save is always "SaveAsync".

Comment: CreateFolder("","").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: the code shown with `.Wait()` is *far from perfect* ("sync over async"), but it should *work* OK (as long as sync-context isn't part of things). What makes you think it is wrong? You say "seems to not stop here" - but: are you sure it hasn't just *finished*?

Comment: In this case I don't have that action available. "await folder.SaveAsync();" does not return anything...

Comment: Depending on the context, this might cause deadlocks...

Comment: btw: `CreateFolder` doesn't really need to be `async` - it *looks* like you could simply remove the `async` modifier and chage the last line to `return folder.SaveAsync();`

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work. Same issue.

Comment: Can you describe how you decided that it is still running async despite your `Wait` call? What happens that makes you think it's not synchronized?